# Get id of selected RadioButton in RadioGroup

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `RadioGroup` like so:

```
    <RadioGroup android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player_age"
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp">
        <RadioButton
                android:text="Male"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="328dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="58dp" android:id="@+id/male"/>
        <RadioButton
                android:text="Female"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="328dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="224dp" android:id="@+id/radioButton4"/>
    </RadioGroup>
```

I've looked through the docs of `RadioGroup` and [`getCheckedRadioButtonId`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup#getCheckedRadioButtonId()) seems to be the most appropriate function to use:

> Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group.
>   Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.

However it returns a useless `Int` and not the id of the `RadioButton`:

```
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_player_details.*

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val name: String = player_name.text.toString()
        val age: Int = player_age.text.toString().toInt()
        val gender: Int = gender.checkedRadioButtonId
        println(name)
        println(age)
        println(gender) // prints 2131361895
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can retrieve the actual `id` of the checked `RadioButton`?

Comment: If you mean to get actual ID using 'R.id.something', the same line returns an integer. Same goes for "getCheckedRadioButtonId".

Comment: How can I get the actual id?

Comment: I have added the answer, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 5):

In a layout file, the attribute `android:id="@+id/male"` means "use the `id` constant named 'male,' and create it if it does not exist". This causes an `int` to be generated in the R.java `R.id` class; if you go look at the actual value of the field `R.id.male`, you will see that it is some seemingly-random number.

When you use `R.id.male` from java code, you are in fact just using some `int` value. So when you get the checked id, and print it, it makes sense to see a "random" number.

However, you can resolve the number back to a `String` representing the name by using the [`Resources.getResourceEntryName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getResourceEntryName(int)) method:

```
val genderId = gender.checkedRadioButtonId // R.id.male, int value 2131361895
val genderString = resources.getResourceEntryName(genderId) // "male"
```